# Splitting an array using .split method javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I apologize if this has been seen before but I am here:

```
var fullName = ["Linus Trovalds "];
var birthYear = [1969];
var myArray = [fullName + birthYear];
console.log(myArray);
```

And I am trying to declare a variable named splitName, and set it equal to fullName split into two separate objects in an array using the split method. In other words, splitName should equal `["Linus", "Torvalds"]` when printed to the console. How should this be written so that split name is printed to the console as mentioned above?

This `split` method is not working for me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.split(delimeter)` is a method for `Strings`. In your code, the variable `fullName` is an Array object because you define it with square brackets `[ ]`. The first and only element within your `fullName` array is a string: so `var nameString = fullName[0]` will give you back the name as a string. Then you can do `var firstLastArray = nameString.split(' ');` to split on the space. Or you could just define `var fullName = "Linus Trovalds "`; as a string instead of an array.

Comment: How does the `birthYear` fit into what you're asking about splitting the value of the name?

Comment: @nnnnnn It probably doesn't. But I used to make same mistakes too.

Comment: @nnnnnn it doesn't at this point but I figured it out.                             
         var fullName  = 'Linus Trovalds';
  var splitName = fullName.split(' ', 2);
  console.log(splitName);

Comment: now I am trying to write a function that when called prints out a string with the where the 1st index value from splitName array is printed. I think I am supposed to use .shift I tried this but no luck:                            
function sayHello();{                                                                                      var splitName = "Linus", "Trovalds";                                                                var firstName = splitName.shift(1);                       
return "Hello,  " + firstName + "!";                 I keep getting a syntax error, any clue why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you have tried it but on top of my head I think you might have forgotten that `fullName` variable is an array.

Try `console.log(fullName[0].split(" "));`

Comment: I figured it out. var fullName = 'Linus Trovalds';                                       
                  var splitName = fullName.split(' ', 2); console.log(splitName);

Comment: now I am trying to write a function that when called prints out a string with the where the 1st index value from splitName array is printed. I think I am supposed to use .shift I tried this but no luck:                                                               function sayHello();{                                                                             
  var splitName = "Linus", "Trovalds";                                                        var firstName = splitName.shift(1);          return "Hello, " + firstName + "!"; I keep getting a syntax error, any clue why?

Comment: @str8up7od `splitName[0]` will give you the first index value. You should read more about arrays

Answer (score 0):

Or you could have simply split the fullName variable at the [5] mark to separate it into two strings in an array:

So it would be (for those looking for this in the future),

```
var fullName = ["Linus Trovalds"];
var birthYear = [1969];
var myArray = [fullName + birthYear];

var splitName = fullName.split(fullName[5])
//which would output ["Linus", "Trivolds"];

console.log(splitName)
//I changed this since I'm assuming you want the output to be the new array
```